# Uncertain how to run Bazel: Tensorflow Inception Retrain New Categories Tutorial Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I am experiencing difficulty using Bazel. More specifically with the workspace requirements. I am not sure how to interpret the following line of code from the TF [Retrain Inception](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/image_retraining/) tutorial.

```
**bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain --image_dir ~/flower_photos**
```

I am able to build the "retrain.py" file. This is my output from my build:

```
*r@r-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/sf_tensorflow-master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining$ bazel build retrain.py

INFO: Found 1 target...

INFO: Elapsed time: 0.200s, Critical Path: 0.01s*
```

But I am uncertain how to proceed with the next step. Is "bazel-bin" a folder somewhere? is it included in the Tensorflow example folder? Or is this something I have to generate?

Also, the way in which "retrain" is being referenced in the code makes me think it is a folder and no longer a python file. Did it change through this process?

I would greatly appreciate a more detailed breakdown of what Bazel is doing in this line of code and how I adjust it to run the code on my directory of images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe to run this example you will have had to have built Tensorflow from source.  It appears you're running some Linux distro; you can find the bazel build instructions [here](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/install.html).  Once you have that installed, you can pull the bleeding edge Tensorflow from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#installing_from_sources) are "building from source" instructions.  Assuming you've done all of that, if you navigate to the root of the project i.e.

```
cd tensorflow
```

you should see something like this

[image]

you can see there are 5 `bazel` symlinks, one of which is `bazel-bin`.

Now just download the images as directed and build with

```
bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain
```

Once the build is finished you can run the retraining

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain --image_dir ~/flower_photos
```

Note that both of the above commands need to be run from the root of the project (`tensorflow/` in this case) and the tutorial assumes you have put the flower images in your home dir.

Hope this helps.

Comment: where is the inception v3 model saved after retrain? searching it via file explorer for "model.ckpt" yields nothing.